# File upload doesnt work with model dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

This code works when if there is only text field to update. But when I tried to upload any file it fails to upload. If I comment the jQuery below then it works but doesn't show me the error in model dialog box.

PHP script:

```
<?php

include_once 'db/Common.php';
include_once 'db/CustomerDB.php';
include_once 'db/CustomerDetails.php';

$cust_id= $_POST ['hidCustId'];

function IsNullOrEmptyString($question){
    return (!isset($question) || trim($question)==='');
}
$uploadSuccess=false;
$files = array_fill(0,8,NULL);
for ($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){

    if(isset($_FILES['file'.$i])){
        $errors= array();


        $file_name = $_FILES['file'.$i]['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['file'.$i]['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['file'.$i]['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['file'.$i]['type'];
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file'.$i]['name'])));

        $files[$i-1] = $file_name;
        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf","docs","doc","exe", "pages");

        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== true){

            //$errors['file'.$i]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }

        if($file_size > 10097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be bellow 10 MB';
        }

        if(empty($errors)==true){


            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uplodedfile/".$file_name);
            $uploadSuccess=true;


        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

}


$customerDB = new CustomerDB ();
$customers = new CustomerDetails ();

$customerArray = $customerDB->selectAllCustomers($cust_id, null, null, null, null);

$customer = $customerArray[0];
$files_old = $customer->get_custFiles();

for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
    if(IsNullOrEmptyString($files[$i])){
        if(!IsNullOrEmptyString($files_old[$i])){
            $files[$i] = $files_old[$i];
        }
    }
}
$customerDB->updateFiles($cust_id,$files);


if ($uploadSuccess) {
    $msgs = "Files updated successfully";
} else {
    $errorMsg = "Error while updating Files details.";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Viewport Metatag -->

    <?php    $common = new Common();  echo $common->get_include_contents('include/css.php')?>



</head>

<body>

<?php

if (! empty ( $msgs )) {
    ?>
    <div class="mws-form-message success">
        This is a success message
        <ol>
            <li><?php echo $msgs; ?></li>
            <li>Close this dialog box to continue.</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php }elseif ($errorMsg){ ?>
    <div class="mws-form-message error">
        This is an error message
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#formEditFiles', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'handleFilesEvent.php',
                    data : data,
                    success :  function(response)
                    {
                        $(".quickNote").html(response);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Try declaring $errorMsg = ""; at the start

Comment: Looks like you use every piece of data in the `$_FILES` array EXCEPT `$_FILES['file'.$i]['error']` Check that its useful to know if PHP is trying to tell you something

Comment: Its rather ODD that you would do all the uploading and then LATER go through and amend the database. Any reason why you dont do that where you do the `move_uploaded_file()`